# How do I translate a string obtained from the internet through Strings.XML?

Tags: android, string, android-resources

I have an app that obtains product names from the internet. The names are in English and I want to translate them to another locale (say Spanish) via the strings.xml that contain their spanish translations.

```
<string name="pick_a_product">Pick a product</string>>
<string name="apple">Apple</string>
<string name="banana">Banana</string>
<string name="cauliflower">Cauliflower</string>
<string name="potatoes">Potatoes</string>
<string name="tomatoes">Tomatoes</string>

<string-array name="product_names">
    <item>@string/pick_a_product</item>
    <item>@string/apple</item>
    <item>@string/banana</item>
    <item>@string/cauliflower</item>
    <item>@string/potatoes</item>
    <item>@string/tomatoes</item>
</string-array>
```

If the app receives the product "Apple", I want it translated to "Manzana" and vice versa depending on the phone/app's current locale. I know that in order to do this I have to search the strings.xml for the id of the string "apple" or "manzana" and set the text using R.string.apple/manzana. But how do I do this?

Here is my current effort. I'm doing this inside an adapter.

```
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {
private Context context;
public ProductAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Product> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView nameTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.productName);


    Product product = getItem(position);


    nameLocalised = getStringResourceByName(product.getName());
    nameTextView.setText(nameLocalised);

}

private String getStringResourceByName(String aString) {
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "string", packageName);
    if (resId == 0) {
        return aString;
    } else {
        return context.getString(resId);
    }
}
}
```

In the **"getStringResourceByName"** method, the resId is always zero.

Comment: That's not really how `strings.xml` is meant to work. String resource names are also case-sensitive, so if you're passing `Apple` to `getStringResourceByName`, it's not going to return anything.

Comment: I'm not trying to edit resource files at runtime. I only want to read them. I want to search for what the resource id for the string "Apple" is.

Comment: you mean the string "apple"

Comment: @KlingKlang R.string.apple is "Apple" in strings.xml. So I want to search using "Apple" to get R.string.apple.

Comment: This is not how the localization resource work. You simply refer R.string.apple and get "Apple" or "Manzana" depending on your current locale. If you want to build a translator, then either use an web service or a local database.

Comment: Yeah I wanted database to be the last resort. Guess I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can get string from `strings.xml` using `getResources().getString(R.string.YourString);`
and for translation in your app you can refer to official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor)

Comment: Thats not what I'm trying to do. I to find the "YourString" based on the string I get from the internet. I want "Apple" to R.string.apple or "Manzana" to R.string.apple.

Comment: you can not modify strings.xml values  at runtime .you can use separate  contract class for storing and manipulating  your string values and or also can use shared preference .